# IOException: Cannot run program "python3"

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am learning the ropes for Apache Spark from the book `Learning Spark Lightning-Fast Data Analysis` . I will provide some context before going to the issue which I encountered.

From the book's instruction, I downloaded Spark from the link below and set up in my local laptop:

```
https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.2.1/spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2.tgz
```

I use Python Interactive Shell in the folder directory which had been extracted from the download link. However, the error occurs when creating RDD with the following code snippet in the interactive shell (Also, You can check the example 2-1 in page 32 of the mentioned book):

```
>>> lines = sc.textFile("README.md") # Create an RDD called lines
>>> lines.count() # Count the number of items in this RDD
```

You can check the error as below:

```
>>> lines.count()
22/05/01 18:09:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 18)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
22/05/01 18:09:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
22/05/01 18:09:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17) (Holyken executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more

22/05/01 18:09:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1237, in count
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1226, in sum
    return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1080, in fold
    vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 950, in collect
    sock_info = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1322, in __call__
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 111, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.3-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 17) (Holyken executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2454)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2402)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1160)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2642)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2584)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2573)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:938)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2235)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2254)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2279)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1030)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:414)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1029)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala:180)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(PythonRDD.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:162)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:337)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

How can I fix the error ? If possible, please assist me to interpret the error so that I am more confident in debugging in the future

Kind regards,

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 0):

The error says that `python3` is not an available command on your system.

So, either make sure that Python3 is installed and on your PATH, or you can modify `spark-env.sh` to set `PYSPARK_PYTHON` to the path of a working Python installation

Alternatively, you could use the `spark-shell` Scala REPL instead of `pyspark`

Comment: I do have python 3.7.9 installed and it is setup in the environment variable Path as D:\Program Files\Python\ - I have some experience with python, therefore I would love to take advantage of it to learn apache Spark. Did I setup correctly as you referred ? Or can you guide me how to setup the spark-env.sh ?

Comment: If you run `python3` in your command prompt, do you get an error about the command not available? The env file is already in the Spark conf folder, you don't need to set it up

Comment: You could also upgrade Python to at least 3.10, and `pip install pyspark`

Comment: for `python3` - I get an error, but for `python` I can access the shell

Comment: Okay, then as mentioned, edit the spark-env.sh and add/set `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python`

Comment: There is a file spark-env.sh.template in the conf folder - I added the `PYSPARK_PYTHON=python` at the end of file and edited the file name to spark-env.sh but when I ran the bin/pyspark again, the command prompt warns as: `Missing Python executable 'python3', defaulting to 'D:\Software\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\bin\..' for SPARK_HOME environment variable. Please install Python or specify the correct Python executable in PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON or PYSPARK_PYTHON environment variable to detect SPARK_HOME safely.`

Comment: Oh oops. Windows doesn't run sh files. Edit/Create `spark-env.cmd` instead. That path is fine for SPARK_HOME, although you can set that yourself as an environment variable, too. You can also add PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=python, but it should default to PYSPARK_PYTHON value

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the os env variables by following the below steps, run this before SparkSession/SparkContext in your notebook

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
os.environ['PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

It worked for me